# Share area of full confidence interval (base graphics)

Tags: r

I am using the following code in R to a plot a linear regression with confidence interval bands (95%) around the regression line.

```
Average <- c(0.298,0.783429,0.2295,0.3725,0.598,0.892,2.4816,2.79975,
             1.716368,0.4845,0.974133,0.824,0.936846,1.54905,0.8166,1.83535,
             1.6902,1.292667,0.2325,0.801,0.516,2.06645,2.64965,2.04785,0.55075,
          0.698615,1.285,2.224118,2.8576,2.42905,1.138143,1.94225,2.467357,0.6615,
             0.75,0.547,0.4518,0.8002,0.5936,0.804,0.7,0.6415,0.702182,0.7662,0.847) 

Area <-c(8.605,16.079,4.17,5.985,12.419,10.062,50.271,61.69,30.262,11.832,25.099,
          8.594,17.786,36.995,7.473,33.531,30.97,30.894,4.894,8.572,5.716,45.5,69.431,
          40.736,8.613,14.829,4.963,33.159,66.32,37.513,27.302,47.828,39.286,9.244,19.484,
          11.877,9.73,11.542,12.603,9.988,7.737,9.298,14.918,17.632,15)

lm.out <- lm (Area ~ Average)
newx = seq(min(Average), by = 0.05)
conf_interval <- predict(lm.out, newdata = data.frame(Average = newx), interval ="confidence",
                         level = 0.95)

plot(Average, Area, xlab ="Average", ylab = "Area", main = "Regression")

abline(lm.out, col = "lightblue")

lines(newx, conf_interval[,2], col = "blue", lty ="dashed")
lines(newx, conf_interval[,3], col = "blue", lty ="dashed")
```

I am stuck because the graph I got reports the bands just for the first part pf the line, leaving out all the remaining line (you find the link to the image at the bottom of the message). What is going wrong? I would also like to  shade the area of the confidence interval (not just the lines corresponding to the limits) but I can't understand how to do it.
Any help would be really appreciated, I am completely new in R.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy with the ggplot2 -library. Here is the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
data = data.frame(Average, Area)
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=Area, y=Average))+
  geom_smooth(method="lm", level=0.95)+
  geom_point()
```

Code to install the library:

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
```